# Changing the primary monitor to be DVI on Mac

Tags: display, macbook

I have a Dell 2408WFP Monitor and a 15inch Macbook Pro (1440 x 900 max resolution).

When I'm home, I would like to use only my Dell monitor (connected via DVI port), instead of having both Macbook display and the Dell monitor side by side.

Is there a way to configure this on Mac?
Only way I can find is making the display to be "mirrored" but then this means I have to use 1440x900 Resolution on my Dell Monitor. I would like to keep 1900x1200 resolution on Dell, and not use the Mac display at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an Apple laptop you can run the computer using only an external monitor by plugging in the DVI cable, and an external keyboard and mouse. You can plug in the the keyboard and mouse and DVI cable and use the keyboard/mouse to wake up the computer with the lid closed - the computer will then only use the external monitor.

You can find more info on the Apple KBase Article: [Apple Portables: How to use your computer in closed clamshell (display closed) mode with an external display](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131)

Comment: Awesome. Now, I just need to go grab my external keyboard... !!

Comment: I always thought this will only work with an Apple keyboard (I don't like em much). Can it now be done with others too? If yes, how?

Comment: In my experience it works with nearly any USB input device. So a non-Apple keyboard, or a non-Apple branded mouse will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

@lexu:

This also now works with Bluetooth mice and keyboards on recent systems that are up to date.

My 8-Core Mac Pro will wake from sleep upon moving my Logitech Bluetooth mouse or hitting a key on my Logitech Bluetooth keyboard.